# Rails find :conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, find, logic, conditional-statements

I have a `Reservation` model that I'm searching for with three fields. The `container_id` must always be `self.id` but as `confirmed` and `auto_confirmed` only one needs to be true. I have the following but it doesn't perform what I need:

```
Reservation.find(:all, 
:conditions => ['container_id = ? AND confirmed = ? OR auto_confirm = ?', 
self.id, true, true,])
```

How should I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm getting your problem, but from what I understand this would work:

```
Reservation.find(:all, 
:conditions => ['container_id = ? AND (confirmed = ? OR auto_confirm = ?)', 
self.id, true, true,])
```

Comment: You ask "only one needs to be true" logically it means row with both are true should not get in resultset.And for this look my answer below.

Comment: @sam If both are true then it will work as well. Then it depends on the logic you want

Comment: Only one must be true means that only one can be true and should not work if both are true

Comment: Only one needs to be true - on my derailed train of thought - means that both can be true but only one needs to be true

Answer (score 3):

As per your question confirmed and auto_confirmed only one needs to be true. So use following

```
Reservation.find(:all, 
                 :conditions => ['container_id = :container AND 
                  ( (confirmed = :flag and auto_confirm != :flag) ||
                    (confirmed != :flag and auto_confirm = :flag))', 
                    {:container=> self.id, :flag=>true}]
               )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't finish the job as simple as the one I checked - and of course this is contingent on how I worded the question. But plus one for your answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
Reservation.find(:all, 
:conditions => ['container_id = ? AND ((confirmed != true AND auto_confirm = true) OR (confirmed = true AND auto_confirm != true))', 
self.id])
```

Comment: this will not work with confirmed = false AND auto_confirm = null just for example though.

Comment: the default values for confirmed and auto_confirm are :false

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is database agnostic, but you could try

```
Reservation.find(:all, 
:conditions => ['container_id = ? AND confirmed = ? **XOR** auto_confirm = ?', 
self.id, true, true,])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is not true - a query like

```
  SELECT * FROM foos WHERE content_id = 345 AND (confirm = 1 OR auto_confirm = 1)
```

will select the rows where both "confirm" columns are set to 1 (and ActiveRecord creates tinyint columns for booleans and checks against 1 and 0).

If you mean **"find all rows matching on the content_id and having EITHER confirmed OR auto_confirmed true but NOT both"** then you come down to a query like this

```
 SELECT * FROM foos WHERE content_id = 345 AND ((confirmed = 1 AND auto_confirm = 0) OR (confirmed = 0 AND auto_confirm = 1))
```

which you reword in AR terms like this

```
  Reservation.find(:all, 
    :conditions => [
      'container_id = ? AND ((confirmed = 1 AND auto_confirm != 1) OR (confirmed = 0 AND auto_confirm != 1))', 
      self]
  )
```

However, judging from the names your fields have you are actually implementing a state machine with separate columns which will bring you pain, so I'd investigate something that would give you progressions of states instead of checking for separate on and off bits.